# How can I import JSON data from web api into SQL table using c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am writing a web app in  ASP .Net Core, where I need to use JSON data from web API. I can get JSON from web using WebClient, so it looks like that in my code:

```
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<credentials>);
   var Json = wc.DownloadString("http://<JSON_String>");
```

JSON data I'm getting:

```
[
{
"ts_num": "6217",
"pl_date_first": "2021-10-01T06:53:07",
"pl_date_last": "2021-10-01T17:36:00",
"pl_num": "2-928558   ",
"pl_vod": "vod1",
"tank1_dn": 0,
"tank2_dn": 19.72,
"tank1_dn_count": 0,
"tank2_dn_count": 3
},
{
"ts_num": "3017",
"pl_date_first": "2021-10-01T06:54:10",
"pl_date_last": "2021-10-01T17:18:30",
"pl_num": "2-928362   ",
"pl_vod": "vod2",
"tank1_dn": 5.44,
"tank2_dn": 34.92,
"tank1_dn_count": 1,
"tank2_dn_count": 5
},
...
```

My problem is, I need to convert this JSON data into SQL table (I have an Azure SQL database), and preferably do it automatically since the data I need transferred to SQL is updating every month. But I couldn't find the way to do it specifically with data from web API. Is there a way to achieve that? Any helpful instructions or links will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the whole JSON to SQL Server and have it break it down into columns and rows

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '
[
{
"ts_num": "6217",
"pl_date_first": "2021-10-01T06:53:07",
"pl_date_last": "2021-10-01T17:36:00",
"pl_num": "2-928558   ",
"pl_vod": "vod1",
"tank1_dn": 0,
"tank2_dn": 19.72,
"tank1_dn_count": 0,
"tank2_dn_count": 3
},
{
"ts_num": "3017",
"pl_date_first": "2021-10-01T06:54:10",
"pl_date_last": "2021-10-01T17:18:30",
"pl_num": "2-928362   ",
"pl_vod": "vod2",
"tank1_dn": 5.44,
"tank2_dn": 34.92,
"tank1_dn_count": 1,
"tank2_dn_count": 5
}]';

INSERT YourTable (
    ts_num,
    pl_date_first,
    pl_date_last,
    pl_num,
    pl_vod,
    tank1_dn,
    tank2_dn,
    tank1_dn_count,
    tank2_dn_count
)
SELECT
    ts_num,
    CONVERT(datetime, pl_date_first, 126),
    CONVERT(datetime, pl_date_last, 126),
    pl_num,
    pl_vod,
    tank1_dn,
    tank2_dn,
    tank1_dn_count,
    tank2_dn_count
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    ts_num int,
    pl_date_first varchar(19),
    pl_date_last varchar(19),
    pl_num varchar(30),
    pl_vod varchar(30),
    tank1_dn int,
    tank2_dn decimal(18,9),
    tank1_dn_count int,
    tank2_dn_count int
) j;
```

Comment: OP is asking for a C# solution, not SQL directly.

Comment: We have no idea exactly what OP wanted anymore, given this Q is over 2 years old. But I think the point was: you can upload the whole JSON to SQL and shred it there.